# Git для программиста-одиночки

Tags: git, phpstorm, bitbucket

Работаю с небольшим проектом, в моем распоряжении:

1. Рабочая станция, на которой я пишу код
2. Тестовый сервер, куда я автоматическим аплоудом загружаю код и смотрю результат, а также запускаю тесты
3. Боевой сервер, на который я загружаю изменения после тестрирования

Хочу работать через Git чтобы была возможность быстро создавать ветки и переключаться между ними.

Я хочу работать примерно так:

1. Пришел отчёт о баге или запрос на добавление функционала
2. Я создал ветку для этого фикса и переключился в неё
3. Написал код, периодически загружая его на тестовый сервер чтобы посмотреть что получилось
4. Код написан, тесты пройдены, делаю коммит и сливаю готовый код в ветку master
5. Оттуда (желательно автоматически) код забирает боевой сервер.

Прочёл много материалов и не понял, как достичь нужного мне воркфлоу. Прежде всего мне непонятно где должен располагаться репозиторий и как с ним работать через Phpstorm.

Comment: Почитайте про git-flow http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: @Nofate, поскольку тут все же русскоязычный Q&A, то было бы хорошо, если бы кто-нибудь (**из пользующих git на практике**) изложил подобное в подробном ответе по русски.

Comment: @avp, за неимением времени: вот перевод http://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то с git вы пока не знакомы. Git отличается от систем предыдущего поколения своей децентрализованностью, т.е. каждый репозиторий действует сам по себе, поэтому вся работа, теоретически, может производиться на одной машине без поднятия каких-либо серверов. После выполнения команды `git init` (в PHPStorm делается через меню) репозиторий сам создастся в корне проекта в виде папки `.git`. Она нам еще пригодится.
Что до "центрального сервера", то я рекомендую завести аккаунт на [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) - это сервис по хранению и управлению гит-репозиториями, который позволяет заводить любое количество приватных репозиториев. Он нам тоже еще понадобится.

Тот воркфлоу, который вы описали, за исключением развертывания и тестов - это практически копия описания `git-flow`. `git-flow` предполагает существование ветки `master`, в которой лежит продакшен-код, и ветки `dev`, в которой лежит текущая версия. Для создания новых фич создаются ветки `feature/some-name`, которые по окончании мерджатся в `dev`; при фиксе багов создаются ветки `hotfix/some-name`, которые мерджатся как в `dev`, так и в `master`.Все это дело, конечно, уже автоматизировано пакетом [gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow), для которого существует плагин в PHPStorm, благодаря которому все эти действия еще упростятся.

С развертыванием есть два (три) пути. Во-первых, гит поддерживает так называемые [хуки](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git), которые позволят вам запускать скрипты при различных действиях с репозиторием, что позволит вам прицепить рукописные скрипты к каким-то действиям. Но это не очень правильно, так как на каждый коммит у вас будет запускаться этот самый скрипт. В случае, если вы завели аккаунт на битбакете, есть альтернативный путь - хуки в самой системе битбакета, которые исполняются при каждой заливке новых коммитов и позволяют сделать HTTP-запрос по определенному URL. Сюда можно прицепить staging и production сервера, заставив их обновляться по подобному запросу. В этом случае придется выписать этим серверам в битбакете по deploy key (самые обычные ssh-ключи), которые будут необходимы для того, чтобы эти сервера могли стянуть свежий код.

Однако, по-хорошему, нужен [дженкинс](https://jenkins-ci.org/), который будет всем этим делом оперировать, иначе, конечно, постоянно придется что-то делать вручную. Дженкинс - это сервер постоянной интеграции, который специально предназначен для автоматизации такого рода процессов. В этом случае хук с битбакета будет посылатсья на дженкинс, который сам будет фильтровать обновленные ветки и на основании их запускать внутренние проекты. В этом случае надо будет сконфигурировать подключение дженкинса по ssh к серверам и создать два проекта - деплой и запуск тестов на staging-сервере и деплой на production-сервере; первый должен запускаться по хукам и выкатывать самую свежию загруженную ветку, а второй - только по кнопке, либо по обновлению ветки мастер.

Если какие-то вещи вы все-таки не знаете, а я подумал обратное, пишите, я дополню ответ.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Comment: Переписал по-человечески.

Comment: Пока хочу без CI. Можно ли в моем случае выстроить такую систему: на тестовом сервере репозиторий Git со всеми ветками. С рабочей станции я только подключаюсь через какой-либо клиент для управления ветками. С боевого сервера я тяну код опять же через гит клиент? (Я до этого использовал SVN и поэтому пока мыслю соответствующими категориями.)

Comment: Да, гит позволяет такие штуки, для него любой репозиторий может служить как источником коммитов, так и приемником, для этого надо будет просто настроить на всех серверах remote (адрес удаленного репозитория, соответствующий адресу на тестововм сервере) и наладить общение по ssh. По поводу CI/CD - вы **уже** им занимаетесь, только можете делать это вручную, а можете в более приличном режиме.

Comment: В случае "потянуть код с тестового сервера на боевой" у меня вопросов нет - git pull, если не ошибаюсь, то с удаленным управлением репозиторием картина пока не ясна. Поясню еще подробнее: на тестовом сервере есть папка с проектом. В этой же папке создан репозиторий. Я хочу, загрузив код в эту папку, сделать коммит. При этом я хочу это сделать со своей рабочей машины. Вот это как я могу сделать?

Comment: При таком сценарии надо будет зайти по ssh и выполнить `git commit -am "Пояснение к коммиту"` или аналог в папке проекта. Я бы делал push в репозиторий на тестовом серваке, а в самом репозитории прописал бы хук на автообновление самого кода, если оно не происходит само по себе (я честно не знаю, как гит себя в этом случае поведет, никогда не делал пуш в не-bare репозиторий).

Comment: я насколько понимаю для netbeans подобное тоже есть?

Comment: @des1roer не знаю, поищите в плагинах *gitflow*, *git flow* или *git-flow* - название общепризнанное, если есть такой плагин, тобудет найден по одному из запросов.

Answer (score 3):

*Это часть решения проблемы, предложенная автором вопроса, Владимиром Зотовым.*

### Получившееся решение

Потратил сутки на эксперименты и чтение документации. В итоге получилось:

1. Рабочая машина с PHPStorm и локальным репозиторием Git
2. Тестовый сервер с папкой проекта и **отдельным расшаренным репозиторием** Git
3. Боевой сервер с локальным репозиторием Git.

Описанный выше воркфлоу реализован (кроме автоматического забора кода на боевой сервер). Получается такая картина:

1. Пришел багрепорт
2. Создаю новую ветку в **локальном** репозитории на рабочей машине. Пишу в ней код, автоматически загружая его на тестовый сервер. В папке проекта на тестовом сервере **нет репозитория** - он размещен отдельно.
3. Загрузил, оттестил код. Делаю коммит в локальной ветке с фиксом. После этого объединяю ветку фикса с веткой мастер.
4. Из ветки мастер делаю push (**через PHPStorm**) в ветку мастер в репозитории на тестовом сервере
5. **Захожу по SSH** на боевой сервер и делаю pull в локальный репозиторий (который лежит в одной папке с проектом) с тестового сервера.

**UPD**: Как показала практика гораздо удобнее загружать код на дев сервер не автоматическим аплоудом из phpstorm а вот этой утилитой http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realsync/. Она по SSH зеркалирует папку проекта на рабочей станции и на дев.сервере. Удобно тем, что при переключении между ветками на рабочей станции - на деве сразу видишь результат. Рекомендую.

**UPD**: Как показала практика - нет особого смысла самому держать центральный репозиторий на дев сервере например - для этого отлично подходит bitbucket.